# How to get the product image in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, product-images, thumbnail, php-7.1

I want to get the product image in Magento 2.

```
$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
                ->addStoreFilter($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId())
                ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name'))
                ->addAttributeToFilter(
                    [
                        ['attribute' => 'name', 'like' => '%' . $searchQuery . '%'],

                    ])
                ->addFieldToFilter('type_id', ['eq' => "sellabletype"]);

            foreach ($collection as $product) {
                $image_url = $this->image->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($product->getSmallImage())->resize(200, 200)->getUrl();
                $searchCollection[] = ['name' => $product->getName(), 'url' => $product->getProductUrl(), 'image' => $image_url];
            }
```

But it return only `Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg url`

How to get product thumbnail image url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was not clear. Do you want to get actual image instead of thumbnail? If not, please elaborate your requirement. If it is that, check it below.

Replace $product->getSmallImage() with $product->getImage() in the below line

From:

```
$image_url = $this->image->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($product->getSmallImage())->resize(200, 200)->getUrl();
```

To:

```
$image_url = $this->image->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($product->getImage())->resize(200, 200)->getUrl();
```

EDITED:

I'm not sure if it is a standard way or not. But try this

```
$imageUrl = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
$productUrl = $imageUrl.'catalog/product'.$product->getImage();
```

Comment: still it returns placeholder url not product thumbnail url

Comment: @ManoM Check the answer I have edited

Comment: .$product->getImage(); returns empty.

Comment: Are you sure, does the product you are searching has images? Coz, $product->getImage() will work if the image exist

Answer (score 0):

you can get image url this way..

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$imageHelper  = $_objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$product = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());
<?php $image_url= $imageHelper->init($product, 'product_thumbnail_image')->setImageFile($product->getFile())->resize(200, 200)->getUrl(); ?>
```

Comment: its return only plcehoder thumbnail image